# matplotlib IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, keras

I am doing a prediction model in keras and trying to plot images from test_generator which I get but I also get this message: "IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1"

this is my code:

```
for images, labels in test_generator:    
    for i in range(6):
        ax = plt.subplot(2, 3, i+1)
        plt.imshow(images[i])
```

test_generator is <keras.preprocessing.image.DirectoryIterator object at 0x00000119EA8F2790>

type(images) is (8, 224, 224, 3) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>,
type(labels) is (8, 4) <class 'numpy.ndarray'>,
batch_size is 8 (if that's important)

Comment: What is your question about this error?

Comment: Size 1 array's only valid index is 0.

Comment: Why do I get this error when iterating? What did I do wrong? @mkrieger1

Comment: You are using the index 1 for an array with size 1 which has 0 as the only valid index.